# Scraping with correct requests for Beautiful Soup - HTML Error 400

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to make a Python program that can gather gene HTML information with Beautiful Soup, but I keep getting errors in making URLs. My code is:

```
# import library for requests 
import urllib.request as urllib
# import library for reading html /
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def fresh_soup(url):    
    '''
    Collects and parses the page source from a given url, returns the parsed page source 
    - url : the url you wish to scrape
    '''
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = urllib.Request(url,headers=hdr) 
    source = urllib.urlopen(req,timeout=10).read() 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source,"lxml")  

    return soup
    ###


import csv

result = []
for line in open("C:/Projects/NCBI Scraper project/geneAccNumbers.txt"):
    result.append(line.split('/t'))

csv = open("C:/Projects/NCBI Scraper project/geneAccNumbers.txt", 'r')
for gene in csv.readline().split('/t'):
    url = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/' + gene + '.1?report=fasta'


def build_url(gene):
    return 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/' + gene + '.1?report=fasta'

genes_urls = [build_url(gene) for gene in csv]


print(genes_urls)

import requests

for url in genes_urls:
    r = requests.get(url)

import urllib.request
for url in genes_urls:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        html = response.read()
    soup = fresh_soup(url)
    result = soup.find_all('pre')
    result = result[0]
    result = result.text
    results +=[result]
```

I keep getting urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request, even though each of the individual URLs generated (when I copy them into a browser after printing) seems to work. This is what they look like:

```
['https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348795\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348740\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348741\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348742\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776060\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776010\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776113\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348743\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776061\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776011\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776114\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348745\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147811\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776115\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348746\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147812\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776116\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348747\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147814\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348748\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147815\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776062\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776012\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776117\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348749\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147816\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348750\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147818\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776118\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348751\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348752\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147819\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348753\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147820\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348754\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147821\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776119\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776063\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776013\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776120\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348755\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348756\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348757\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348758\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147822\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348759\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147823\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776064\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776014\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776121\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348761\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147825\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776122\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776065\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776015\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776123\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776066\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776016\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776124\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776067\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776017\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348763\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776068\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776018\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776125\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348764\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147828\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348765\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147829\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776126\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348766\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147830\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348767\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147831\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776127\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348768\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348769\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147832\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348770\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147833\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348771\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147834\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776069\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776019\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776128\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776070\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776020\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776129\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348773\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147836\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776130\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348774\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147837\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348776\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147838\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776071\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776021\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776131\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348777\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348778\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147841\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776132\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776072\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776022\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776133\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348780\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348781\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147843\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348782\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147844\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348783\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147846\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348784\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147847\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776073\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776023\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776134\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348785\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348786\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348787\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776074\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776024\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776135\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776075\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776025\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776136\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348790\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348791\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147849\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348792\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AB043642\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348793\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776076\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776027\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776077\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776028\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776137\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348796\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147851\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348797\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147852\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348798\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776029\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776138\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348799\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147853\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348800\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776078\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776030\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776079\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776031\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776139\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348802\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147855\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776080\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776032\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776140\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348803\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147856\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348804\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776081\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776033\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776141\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776082\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776034\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776142\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776083\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776035\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776143\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348805\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776084\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776036\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348806\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147858\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348807\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147859\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776085\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776144\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348809\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348810\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147860\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776086\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776037\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776145\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348811\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147861\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776146\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776087\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776038\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776147\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348812\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147862\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776088\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776039\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776148\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776089\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776040\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776149\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776090\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776041\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776150\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776091\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776042\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776151\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776092\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147864\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776152\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348814\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147865\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348815\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348816\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147866\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348817\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776094\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776153\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776093\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776043\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348818\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147867\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776154\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348819\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147868\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776095\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776044\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776155\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348820\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147870\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776096\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776026\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776156\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348821\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776045\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776157\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348822\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147871\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776097\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776046\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776158\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348823\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147872\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776098\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147873\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776159\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348824\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776047\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776160\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348825\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147874\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348827\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348828\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147876\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776161\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348829\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776099\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147877\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776162\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776100\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776048\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776163\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348830\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147878\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776101\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776049\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348832\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147879\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348833\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147880\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776164\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776102\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776050\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776165\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348835\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147881\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348836\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348837\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776103\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776051\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776166\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776104\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776052\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776167\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348838\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147882\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348839\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348840\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147883\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348841\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776168\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776105\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776053\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776169\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/FJ826677\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776106\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776054\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776170\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348843\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147885\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776107\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776055\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776171\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348844\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147886\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776108\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776056\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776172\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348845\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147887\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776173\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776109\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AB043527\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776174\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348847\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147890\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348848\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348849\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147892\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AB043641\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776110\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776057\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776175\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776111\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776058\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776176\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348850\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147893\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776112\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776059\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/KP776177\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348852\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348853\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147895\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147897\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348855\n.1?report=fasta', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/DQ147898.1?report=fasta']
```

What is it I can do to make it correctly request the URLs and scrape?

Comment: use the requests module and no urllib to simplify things. Dont mix them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your URLs you have \n. This needs to be stripped out. There is no pre tag in the HTML so in this example I have found the second h1 tag to test with.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# In your function you need to strip out "\n" as it has no place in your URLs.
def build_url(gene):
    return 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/' + gene.rstrip() + '.1?report=fasta'

csv = open("C:/Projects/NCBI Scraper project/geneAccNumbers.txt", 'r')
genes_urls = [build_url(gene) for gene in csv]

results = []
for url in genes_urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    # Using html.parser but you can use lxml if you like.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser") 
    # there is no <pre> tag in the soup so we will find the second occurrence of H1 for testing.
    result = soup.find_all('h1')[1].text
    print (result)
    results +=[result]

print (results)
```

Outputs:

```
Impatiens amoena internal transcribed spacer 1, 5.8S ribosomal RNA gene, and internal transcribed spacer 2, complete sequence
Impatiens amphorata internal transcribed spacer 1, 5.8S ribosomal RNA gene, and internal transcribed spacer 2, complete sequence
Impatiens andohahelae internal transcribed spacer 1, 5.8S ribosomal RNA gene, and internal transcribed spacer 2, complete sequence
Impatiens andringitrensis internal transcribed spacer 1, 5.8S ribosomal RNA gene, and internal transcribed spacer 2, complete sequence
Impatiens angulata voucher S.X. Yu 3777 internal transcribed spacer 1, partial sequence; 5.8S ribosomal RNA gene, complete sequence; and internal transcribed spacer 2, partial sequence
Impatiens angulata voucher S.X. Yu 3777 atpB-rbcL intergenic spacer, partial sequence; chloroplast
Impatiens angulata voucher S.X. Yu 3777 tRNA-Leu (trnL) gene, partial sequence; trnL-trnF intergenic spacer, complete sequence; and tRNA-Phe (trnF) gene, partial sequence; plastid
Impatiens anovensis internal transcribed spacer 1, 5.8S ribosomal RNA gene, and internal transcribed spacer 2, complete sequence
Impatiens apalophylla voucher S.X. Yu 4042 internal transcribed spacer 1, partial sequence; 5.8S ribosomal RNA gene, complete sequence; and internal transcribed spacer 2, partial sequence
....
```

**Updated**
The pre tag is generated by a XHR request made by JavaScript. You can simulate it like this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# In your function you need to strip out "\n" as it has no place in your URLs.
def build_url(gene):
    return 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/' + gene.rstrip() + '.1?report=fasta'

csv = open("C:/Projects/NCBI Scraper project/geneAccNumbers.txt", 'r')
genes_urls = [build_url(gene) for gene in csv]

results = []
for url in genes_urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    # Using html.parser but you can use lxml if you like.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    # You need to get the vale of content in <meta content="38155510" name="ncbi_uidlist"/>
    content = soup.find('meta', {'name':"ncbi_uidlist"})['content']
    # Simulate the XHR request using "content"
    result = requests.get("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=" + content + "&db=nuccore&report=fasta&extrafeat=null&conwithfeat=on&retmode=ht").text
    print (result)
    results +=[result]

print (results)
```

Outputs:

```
>AY348795.1 Impatiens amoena internal transcribed spacer 1, 5.8S ribosomal RNA gene, and internal transcribed spacer 2, complete sequence
TCGAAAACTATTTCAAACAACCAGTGAACATAATAATAAATCTTGTGTTGAGATTGACTTTTGTTTAATC
TCTTCCTATTAATGTACTTGGAGTGCTTGCTTGGCAACAAATTTGTATGCCATTTTGTAGGTTCCCTCAA
CTCATAAACAAACCCCGGCGTAAACCGCCAAGGAATGTTAAAAACAATTGCCATTATTTTACCCATTTAT
ATGGGATGAAATTTTGGTTTTAGTTATCAATAAACTAAAATGACTCTCGACAACGGATATCTCGGCTCTC
GCATCGATGAAGAACGTAGCAAAATGCGATACTTGGTGTGAATTGCAGAATCCCGTGAACCATCGAGTTT
TTGAACCCAAGTTGCGCCTGAAGCTATTAGGTTGAAGGCACGTCTGCCTGGGCGTCTCGCTTCGTGTCGT
CTCATTTCATCTATTATGGGACGGATAATGGCCTCCTGTACGTTTATATATCGAGCAGTTGGTTGAAATA
TAAGTCCATATTATAGGACACACGGTTAGTGGTGGTTGAAAAAACTGTTTCAAACCCGTGTTGTAACTTA
ATTTGGATTGATTGACCCTTCTTGTGCCTTTAATGGTGCATCGTTTGC

>AY348740.1 Impatiens amphorata internal transcribed spacer 1, 5.8S ribosomal RNA gene, and internal transcribed spacer 2, complete sequence
TTCATCACCGNCGAACTTGTTATTAAAATCGGGCTGCGATTGGCCTTTGGNCGGTCGCTTCCCATCATGC
GGTTGGGGTGCACGGTGTTGTATTCTATCTTGGGTACAATCGCGTGTTCCCCCNACTCATAAACAAACCC
CGGCGTAAACCGCCAAGGAATGTTAAAAAGGACTTCCCATACCAGACCCATTTTATTTTTGGGGGATGCG
TAATGGTGTTAGTTTTCCATAAACATAACGACTCTCGACAACGGATATCTCGGCTCTCGCATCGATGAAG
AACGTAGCAAAATGCGATACTTGGTGTGAATTGCARAATTCCCGTGAACCATCGAGTTTTTGAACGCAAG
TTGCGCCTGAAGCCATTAGGTTGAGGGCACGTCTGCCTGGGCGTCTCGCTTCGTGTCGCCCCATTTCATA
ACTGTTTTGGGACGTATAATGGCCTCCTGTGCAATACCCATGCAGCAGTTGGCCGAAATAGAAGTCCATA
TGATAGGACACACGGTTAGTGGTGGTTGARAAACTGTTTC
...
```

Comment: Great response, thank you! So what exactly does the h1 you're talking about specify? I see that it generates that species and gene information, which I do want, but I also want the actual sequences, A's T's G's and C's. Is that specified by a different tag? How do I know which one to use for both parts of the file from <pre> that I want?

Comment: Updated in response to comment.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests, bs4

results = []
for url in genes_urls:
    html = requests.get(url.strip(), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    results += [soup.find('pre').text]
```

and please delete all of the other networking code because its just awful copy pasted from different locations. Use the above code to receive the data from a list of urls.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but got a warning that said I'm using BS to make a request when I should use Request: "UserWarning: "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY348795
.1?report=fasta" looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should probably use an HTTP client like requests to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup" How do I get the documents (the scraped parts of the websites) behind the URL and feed it to BS like it says?

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully this works for you now! Basically you download the source code of the website (the html document) using requests (or urllib, i recommend requests) as you can see in my answer. Then you parse the html using BS.